# Why does `vagrant up` cause the VirtualBox VM window to appear?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

After following the vagrant tutorial everything seems to be going fine. However something new and slightly annoying has started happening when I run `vagrant up`: VirtualBox also starts up and I see a VM window which seems to correspond to the Vagrant VM open. I've used Vagrant many times in the past without this happening, and IIRC *even for this current vm that I'm using* VirtualBox wouldn't necessarily open just because I ran `vagrant up`.

What is causing this? Why does `vagrant up` cause the VirtualBox VM window to appear? (and steal focus from my Mac OS X Terminal window, which is quite annoying)

Note: The answer in my case is *not* that Vagrant uses VirtualBox. If this were the case then VirtualBox would have always been opening in the background and I'm quite sure this is a new behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see three possibilities:

- In your Vagrantfile, you configured gui = True ([see GUI vs Headless](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html))
- The box you use with Vagrant comes with gui = True setting in its Vagrantfile (Box contains initial Vagrantfile which is being merged when you do `vagrant up`)
- Possible bug in Vagrant and/or VirtualBox

It could be helpful if you specify your Vagrant & VirtualBox versions, and share with us your Vagrantfile.

Comment: Point 1 fixed it for me. In my case it was a cavalier copy-paste from a default Vagrantfile that included the line `vb.gui = true`. Commenting that out fixed the issue so that the VirtualBox window never appears any more.